# decreasing and increasing float increment android

Tags: java, android, audio, increment

I am trying to increase and decrease the volume of tones via onscreen buttons. I have the code here:

```
//variables
float leftVolume = 0.5f;
float rightVolume = 0.5f;

public void lowerVolume(View view)
{ float decrement = 0.2f;
    rightVolume -= decrement;
    leftVolume -= decrement;
    Log.d("Values","This is the value of volume"+ leftVolume);
}

public void raiseVolume(View view)
{ float increment = 0.2f;
    rightVolume = ++increment;
    leftVolume = ++increment;
    Log.d("Values","This is the value of volume"+ rightVolume);
}
```

the log is showing up some crazy values, such as hen i click rasieVolume, it goes to 1.2f and stays there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are setting the float value to 1.2 each time you call `raiseVolume()`.

```
public void raiseVolume(View view)
{ float increment = 0.2f; //you set increment here
    rightVolume = ++increment; //then simply increase it by 1
    leftVolume = ++increment;

    //...and so your volume will always be 1.2 at this point
    Log.d("Values","This is the value of volume"+ rightVolume);
}
```

The way to solve this is to set the volume to an initial value OUTSIDE of the `raiseVolume()` method (which you already do), and then increment it INSIDE the `raiseVolume()` method.

Like this:

```
//variables
float leftVolume = 0.5f;
float rightVolume = 0.5f;

public void raiseVolume(View view)
{ float increment = 0.2f;
    rightVolume += increment; //change this line to this
    leftVolume += increment;  //change this line to this
    Log.d("Values","This is the value of volume"+ rightVolume);
}
```

Comment: ahhh i understand now thanks. So how would i get it to decrease by the 0.2 each time the button is clicked? sorry if this is obvious!

Comment: From the look of your original code, your `lowerVolume()` method should work as intended. The statement `rightVolume -= decrement;` should correctly decrement your volume level. Glad to help, and please accept my answer if you feel it solved your issue!

Answer (score 0):

It's because this code will increase `increment` to `1.2f`:

```
 rightVolume = ++increment;
```

then `rightVolume` will be `1.2f`,and `leftVolume` will be `2.2f`.

So you should change the value like you do in `lowerVolume`:

```
rightVolume += increment;
leftVolume += increment;
```

Answer (score 0):

each time you are increment increment value by 1 and assining it to right or left Volume, use following.

```
rightVolume += increment;
leftVolume += increment;
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers given are correct in the strict sense but I just wanted to point out that a typical audio volume control is log tapered and not linear. This has to do with the perception of loudness. If you want to follow that model then you want to multiply and divide instead of add and subtract. Also, another side note: audio volumes used in any digital signal processing are going to want to stay in the range of 0 to 1 where 1.0 means full output level and 0 is muted. If you want that behavior then you should also clip the the values to be <=1.0 in the raiseVolume procedure.

```
//variables
float leftVolume = 0.5f;
float rightVolume = 0.5f;

public void lowerVolume(View view)
{ 
   float decrement = 0.5f;
   rightVolume *= decrement;
   leftVolume *= decrement;
}

public void raiseVolume(View view)
{ 
    float increment = 2.0f;
    rightVolume *= increment;
    leftVolume *= increment;
}
```